# Probability of flipping an infinite number of heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is a bit of a Philosophical question, perhaps. Suppose I flip a fair coin a countably infinite number of times. Then the probability of getting 'heads' every time is 
$$\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2}=0$$
But in the physical universe, there is nothing that physically prevents this from happening, so to say it has zero probability seems wrong...

So what's going wrong here? Is this just an example where mathematics does not reveal anything about reality? Or is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: What physically prevents it from happening is that you never have time for an infinite number of coin tosses.

Comment: How would you flip a coin an infinite number of times in this "physical universe"?

Comment: "Suppose I flip a fair coin a countably infinite number of times" -- I've got some bad news...

Comment: I was hoping 'time' wouldn't be the problem. Can't we assume my descendants will be around forever to keep this up?

Comment: That an event has probability 0 of occurring does not mean it cannot occur, and given it has occurred does not mean its probability was greater than 0.

Comment: You can't talk about the physical world and also hope that physical constraints like time, gravity, or proton decay, will not pose a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flipping a fair coin a countable number of times gives an uncountable number of outcomes. Somehow, the probabilities of all these outcomes must add to one. But the only way that this can happen is if almost all of the probabilities are zero. In probability theory, a situation which could occur, but which has a zero probability is called an "almost impossible outcome." It doesn't mean that the outcome cannot happen, but for any positive number $x$, the probability of the outcome occurring is less than $x$. So the only number which could be the probability is zero.

Answer (score 1):

To be exact the probability of *any particular* atomic outcome in the uncountably *infinite* set of possible outcomes is *almost surely zero*, yet the probability that *some outcome* occurs is certainly one. 
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P\{\omega\} & = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \tfrac 1 2 & \forall \omega\in\Omega \\[1ex] & =0\textsf{ a.s.}
\\[2ex] \mathsf P(\bigcup\limits_{\omega\in \Omega}\{\omega\}) & = \mathsf P(\Omega) \\[0ex] & = 1
\end{align}$$

It's as though such a probability is not actually zero, just so *infinitesimally close* to zero that we cannot give it a *real* measure.   Thus we say the particular event is not actually impossible, just *almost surely* so.

Comment: "in the countably infinite set of possible outcomes " Did you mean "uncountably"?

Comment: "$P\{\omega\}=0\text{ a.s.}$" is a category error, since "$P\{\omega\}=0$" is not an event -- "[almost sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)" applies standardly to an *event* whose probability equals $1$. The opposite extreme might be called "almost impossible", i.e., an event with probability equal to $0$. Thus, in your example, $P\{\omega\}=0$ (*exactly*, not "almost surely"), so each atomic event $\{\omega\}$ is *almost impossible* and its complement $\Omega\backslash\{\omega\}$ is *almost sure*.